# Populating ms sql with sql files

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, mysql, sqlcmd

I already have an existing database I am trying to keep up to date on a daily basis. I get a daily dump of sql files. The batch script below created and populated the database the first time I run it, but that doesn't work when I try to update the database with it.

```
`@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt


for %%f in (*.sql) do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S servername -E   -d DatabaseName -i %%f >>output.txt
    )
pause`
```

Is there a different command for updating a database with sql files?
This is the output i get.

```
HUTRC started the batch process at 9:55:12.25 Changed database context to 'master'. Msg 15416, Level 16, State 1, Server HUTRC1-HP, Procedure sp_dbcmptlevel, Line 67 Usage: sp_dbcmptlevel [dbname [, compatibilitylevel]] Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.
```

What the sql file looks like. It is very long. I just got the first few lines.

```
USE [master]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'Migration')
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE [Migration] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
END
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname=N'Migration', @new_cmptlevel=90
```

Comment: Can you describe in what way this "doesn't work"? Also, what is the content of the sql files you are trying to load?

Comment: This is the output I get.

HUTRC started the batch process at  9:55:12.25  
Changed database context to 'master'.
Msg 15416, Level 16, State 1, Server HUTRC1-HP, Procedure sp_dbcmptlevel, Line 67
Usage: sp_dbcmptlevel [dbname [, compatibilitylevel]]
 
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.

Comment: So what is the value in your SQL file being passed for database compatibility level? The error clearly says you're providing something other than the proper value (100, 110, or 120). You didn't include the content of the SQL script that's causing the error, so we can't read it for you.

Comment: I cleaned up some of the comment clutter after posting an answer. You may want to do the same, as they're no longer relevant. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you precisely where to look for the problem and what it is (**emphasis added**):

> Procedure sp_dbcmptlevel, Line 67 Usage: **sp_dbcmptlevel [dbname [, compatibilitylevel]] Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.**

Examining your SQL script for `sp_dbcmptlevel` shows that it uses a different value:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname=N'Migration', @new_cmptlevel=90
                                                             ^^
```

You'll need to either edit the SQL script to a valid compatibility level, or downgrade your server version to the same version as the source server.